# Fitting linear regression model with sparse matrix predictors and sparse matrix response

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, sparse-matrix

What's the best way to get a least squares fit with a matrix response when using sparse matrices? Both my matrix of regressors and my matrix of responses are sparse. In my particular case, they are many-valued factors and those factors interacted with count variables.

`slm.fit` from the `SparseM` package is one option, but it seems that there is no easy way to construct `SparseM` model matrices. All the examples create them using a dense matrix and then convert, or read it from a file. This means I could construct the model matrix using Matrix, then write it to a file, and then read it in using SparseM. Not exactly a great solution.

`speedlm`, `sparse.lm.fit`, and `glm4` all seem to not handle Matrix responses. I could simply run `speedlm` once for each column of the response matrix, but this is quite inefficient.